# Handling multiple requests from a same client in a series of small time frames

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, request

I have developed a web application that contains a dashboard to display various reports and graphs based on user selections.

The user is provided with checkboxes and radio buttons for operating on the reports as required. On selection of each checkbox and radio button, I am making an ajax call to display the report corresponding to the selections.

The problem I am facing is when the user clicks on multiple checkboxes/radio button one by one in a series with a very small time gap (fraction of a second or a second), the requests are hit to the server in a series and the server responds to them in the same order.

*For example, if I have 2 radio buttons, one for pie chart and other for line graph, and the user clicks both of them in a series of small time gap, the server displays the pie chart first and within few milliseconds it is overwritten by the line graph.*

> Is there a mechanism, which will enable me to override the latest
>   request over all the earlier request?

**Notes:**

1. I do not want to hit the server continuously, at the same time, I do not want to provide a submit button (against the customer requirement).
2. It would be great if I find a javascript/ajax mechanism that allows me to submit only the latest request to the server.
3. I am using Java/J2EE Struts2 framework, javascript and ajax

Comment: So, if I've understood well in your example, the correct behavior would be only display the line graph?

Comment: Why to not add delay before sending request to server? I.e. user hits radio button -> js client is queueing that event -> user clicks on other button -> js client rewrites last event -> user does nothing 1 sec -> js client sends last request.

Comment: @A-Tomy-k: Yes, since the latest request is for line graph, the correct behavior here would be to display line graph.

Comment: @pbespechnyi: I believe, putting a delay would just slow down this process. For instance, if the user makes changes exactly after one second it would still execute both the request. 1 sec is just a common interval which occurs repeatedly.

Comment: @VirajPai, yes, this will not prevent all unnecessary requests, but this decrease amount of such reqs to service. Also, this will prevent your client to redraw ui on every user's click.

Answer (score 0):

Define an interval, basically a longer, home-made `event-loop` to batch or send just the latest request:

```
var timeoutID

function formChangeHandler() {

  clearTimeout(timeoutID)

  timeoutID = setTimeout(function() { 
    // send data to server
  }, 1000);

}
```

This is just one of many possible approaches, in this case the server would only receive data after 1000ms have gone by without activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that there're two different ways of dealing the problem.

The first possibility is using a little delay, as other users have said.

- Advantage: The first request is never sent (you save server load).
- Disadvantage: The request is delayed always, so the user has to wait although he makes an individual request.

The second possibility is to abort the first request when another comes.

- Advantage: The requests are dealt in realtime.
- Disadvantage: The requests are always sent to the server.

I leave here a code fragment that should works for the second option. Probably you have to make some changes, I haven't proved it but this is the main idea:

```
var xhr = null; // handles the current request

function sendRequest(){

    if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
        // When a request is made and another is ongoing, abort the previous
        xhr.abort(); 
    }

    xhr = $.ajax({
        .
        .
        . // Request parameters   
        done: function(data){
            // do something
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to be what I need, but as I am using 
`dojo.event.topic.publish("showtprogressReport");`
I am not getting any return type. So just wondering, is it mandatory to use jquery ajax or can is go ahead with Struts2 ajax?

Comment: I do not know if I am doing it right. But I have just tried this:
    `var xhr = null;
    function submitForm() {
    document.getElementById("secondLevelReportDisplayDiv").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("tprogressReport").innerHTML = '<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/struts/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>';
     if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
      xhr.abort(); 
     }
     xhr = $.ajax({
      done: function(){
       dojo.event.topic.publish("showtprogressReport");
      }
      });
    }`  
     Please suggest as it seems to be publishing only the first time.

Comment: I have never worked with Dojo, so I can't really help with it. It seems that Dojo.publish doesn't return anything, as you have said. Your code is wrong because you don't need to use JQuery ($.ajax) to make the ajax call (publish does it automatically). Check this page, you will probably find something useful http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/publish.html **connect.subscribe** returns a handler. Doing a connect.unsubscribe(handler) could work